# Where the view classes should be instantiated in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller

If i follow MVC pattern, which place is the rightmost to instantiate the view classes ?

Is it inside

1. Main class
2. Model
3. View
4. Controller

I prefer instantiating the view classes inside a controller called InstantiateViewsCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code adheres to [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) then you would see the instantiation of view as another responsibility. Which in turn would mean that it has no place in controller.

Instead it is a dependency of the controller.

> <sub>Options 2 and 3 are obviously wrong, because point of MVC is to separate business logic from presentation and class should not instantiate themselves.</sub>

Which means that the views should be instantiate somewhere near where controllers are instantiated.

Though, I have no idea what "main class" is in your question. Sounds like some pointless artifact of language (as if using classes would automagically make it OOP).

Comment: OK, So, where the controllers should be instantiated ? By Main class i mean, the very first class of the program. From where on can start instantiating the MVC pattern.

Comment: I prefer instantiating view classes inside a controller, because that way i can control the instantiation. I may or may not want to instantiate some views according to their importance as per the state of the application.

Comment: I think you might be confusing views with templates. Views, in an adequately implemented MVC, are instances that are responsible for display logic. Said view acquires data from model layer and, based on the received information, chooses which templates (if any) to use for creation of response. Unless you are using some variations of HMVC, you would be using **one** view at the time.